# Feels like ABS but I dont think it is

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, avalanche

I have a 2004 Chevy Avalanche. Was having and issue with brake pedal pulsing, but it started when I applied my brakes quickly after starting to pull out from a store. Replaced my pads, and the sensation went away for a couple of weeks, and now it is back. The pads I removed were unevenly worn. They had kicked off at an angle and the bottom was wearing more than the top. The new pads did not fit in the glides right, but made it work. Wondering if this is a caliper issue. Pulled ABS fuse and the pedal still pulses, so I am ruling out a wheel sensor.

Comment: Rotor wear on inside and outside surfaces are no longer parallel as they were when new. Rotors are either machined to like new condition or discarded. Complete disc brake repairs requires attention to details.

Answer (score 5):

A warped rotor will cause pulsating. But the pulsating is more in line with wheel rotation instead of a rapid pulsation caused by ABS. Uneven wear on pads indicate problems with the brake system. Sticking calipers, sticking slides and defective brake hoses will cause both uneven pad wear and warped rotors.